# Make dev_appserver.py listen for changes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-app-engine-python

I'm working on a Python 3 Flask app and running `dev_appserver.py` to test locally.

I'm finding that when I modify my Jinja templates, the local instance doesn't seem to pick up those changes, even when I hard refresh in my browser. The only way I've been able to pick up changes is to kill the script and run it again.

I didn't find any mention of this in the official documentation and `--help` only mentions one relevant flag, and it says that by default the watcher ignores nothing:

```
  --watcher_ignore_re WATCHER_IGNORE_RE
                        Regex string to specify files to be ignored by the
                        filewatcher. (default: None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass extra files to `Flask().run()` like the following:

```
from os import path, walk

extra_dirs = ['directory/to/watch',]
extra_files = extra_dirs[:]
for extra_dir in extra_dirs:
    for dirname, dirs, files in walk(extra_dir):
        for filename in files:
            filename = path.join(dirname, filename)
            if path.isfile(filename):
                extra_files.append(filename)
    

app.run(extra_files=extra_files)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I double-checked that the `extra_files` generation works correctly in a Python shell. My last line is `app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True, extra_files=extra_files)`, but template changes still don't appear on refresh.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I set `app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True` and it works, but only for the first template change. The local server doesn't seem to pick up any subsequent changes. Tried hard refreshing and using an incognito window just to be sure.